# PHP script to redirect traffic based on website accessed

Tags: php, functions, multisite

I manage several websites (eg. www.website1.com, www.website2.com) and would like to write a php to redirect traffic accordingly. I would have a PHP script that resides in the `mu-plugins` folder. So if someone access www.website1.com, they would be redirected to a certain site while if someone access website2.com, they would be redirected to another site.

Could someone let me know what function I could use to detect the website the user accesses? I don't believe the PHP script below would work because my website is self-hosted and so doesn't have a blog id?

Thank you.

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return; // Not applicable.
}
if ( 123 !== get_current_blog_id() ) {
    return; // Not on blog ID 123.
}
if ( ! is_page( 90 ) ) {
    return; // Not a specific page ID on this blog.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am not absolutely sure what you mean but probably something like this may help you:

```
if( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_NAME' ] == 'website1.com' ):

    header( 'Location: https://www.example.com/w1' ); exit;

elseif( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_NAME' ] == 'website2.com' ):

    header( 'Location: https://www.example.com/w2' ); exit;

endif;
```

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks for the reply. Apologies for not being clear enough. I have revised the code in my original post. What happens is that I want to have a script that does the following (1) is website = www.website1.com? (2) If it is www.website1.com, then is it page 90? If not the script just ends. I would have another PHP file with both (1) and (2) just that it is www.website2.com instead of website1.com. thank you.

Comment: Still don't get it ... sorry. So you have a WordPress network aka multisite installation and want that each site/blog is available from a different domain?